# How does GNUCash calculate "profits"

Tags: gnucash

At the bottom is a summary bar, which shows "Net Assets" and "profits". I'm slightly baffled at what GNUCash thinks profits are, since it seems to be different than "net worth".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is different than "net worth", isn't it?

Profits = income - expenses

Net assets = assets - liabilities.

Comment: by that measure, I should have 45k in profits, not 10. Is there some accounting period perhaps?

Comment: Looks like it is for the current year. Also, make sure you categorize your accounts correctly. You can see the calculation in the "Profit & Loss" report.